# Django - Cannot login when subclassing User model

Tags: django, django-models, django-contrib

I searched for a similar question but found none so far.

I have a subclass of User (django.contrib.auth.models.User). I want my site to support both Individual users and Business users, so in this case it's:

```
class BusinessUser(User):
    website = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    objects = UserManager()
```

I have a register form that saves a user as a User and another one that saves my user as a BusinessUser. The problematic case is the BusinessUser:

I have checked through the Django console that both an User and a BusinessUser object exists after registration of a BusinessUser, and all fields are fine (username, email, password).

However, on my login page, I cannot login with my BusinessUser's. I can login fine with the normal User's registered, but not BusinessUser's.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You subclassed `User`. Don't do that *ever*. Use profiles to add additional data, and if you really need two separate models (say for having two separate views for individual and business users in the admin) create proxy models and custom managers that filter only individual or business users from `User`.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was thinking of doing it like this:

In the UserProfile model have two booleans, for individual user and business, and a BusinessProfile and IndividualProfile that would be null or not null accordingly.

I thought the subclass way would be more efficient as this approach always has two unused variables in the class.

If I can't subclass, would you recommend an approach like this, then?

Comment: That's the typical approach, but I wouldn't use two fields. Set it up as a `CharField` or `PositiveIntegerField` and then set the `choices` attribute to a tuple of `(<value>, <name>)` pairs. Make sure to include an empty option and you probably want to make that the default.

Comment: Chris, why do you say never subclass the User class?  It seems to be now the way to do it: http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

Comment: @Kave: Note that that post is from 2008, yet if you look at the dev docs for Django, they *still* recommend using a separate profile model. Sure, as the post explains, you can cobble together some solution that will *mostly* work, but remember that it's not just about your app, but other 3rd-party apps, and even potentially apps that might one day integrate yours. Following convention ensures that everything just works, and frankly there's not much a good argument against using a separate profile unless you're truly that concerned about one extra DB query.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I wasn't aware that Django team still recommends going the profile path. When I was doing some research today it seemed that the inheritance came later than the profile approach and was meant to be an improvement.

Comment: Inheritance was added in general. Originally, Django models had very limited to no ability to inherit from other models. This wasn't added for the purpose of extending User; the writer of that blog post merely siezed the opportunity to use it for extending User. However, that was misguided at best.

Comment: For clarification, in django 1.5 the user profile setup has been changed.  Make sure you check the documentation and confirm if you are on 1.5 or <1.5.  They are completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Custom authentification backend should be used when django's `User` subclassed

You can see example [here](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/)

I haven't tested this, but I believe this will work.